# How can I implement a countdown for items in a todo list web app?

Tags: django, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have made a todo list webapp in Django. It is a simple CRUD web App. Now upon creation of an item for the todo list the user specifies a duration for which that item's status remains "to be completed". If the user fails to complete a task in the duration set for an item in the todo list, that item's status should automatically change to "not completed".

Should a scheduled job be used to poll the app and change the status accordingly? Wouldn't polling the app constantly be costly?

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a scheduled job to check on items. For example, on Heroku, setting up jobs does not cost anything.

Also, you can run a query when the user logged in to check on his specific items. So, you do not have to run a job for nothing (if no item status should be change); and you run a query only on items related to the user, not on the full database.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of checking items for the user when they log in. It would be alot better than setting up a scheduled task for the entire database.